# FriendlyARM Mini210s - Installing yaffs2-image failed

Tags: arm

Trying to use default images provided with [FriendlyARM mini210s](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210s) SBC.

Got the images from the DVDs that you can download on ftp.friendlyarm.net [credentials at the bottom of this page](http://www.friendlyarm.net/downloads) under the `mini210` folder.

- Prepare microSD using `SD-Flashed.exe` on Windows XP machine
- Copied images folder onto the microSD

### My FriendARM.ini

```
#This line cannot be removed. by FriendlyARM(www.arm9.net)

CheckOneButton=No
Action = Install
OS = Linux

LowFormat = Yes
VerifyNandWrite = No

LCD-Mode = No
LCD-Type = A70
CheckCRC32=No

StatusType = Beeper | LED

################### Linux ####################
Linux-BootLoader = Superboot210.bin
Linux-Kernel = Linux/zImage
Linux-CommandLine = root=/dev/mtdblock4 rootfstype=yaffs2 console=ttySAC0,115200 init=/linuxrc
Linux-RootFs-InstallImage = Linux/rootfs_qtopia_qt4-mlc2.img

################### Android 4.0.3 ####################
Android-BootLoader = Superboot210.bin
Android-Kernel = Android/zImage
Android-CommandLine = root=/dev/mtdblock4 rootfstype=yaffs2 console=ttySAC0,115200 init=/linuxrc androidboot.console=ttySAC0 gs=0
Android-RootFs-InstallImage = Android/rootfs_android-mlc2.img
```

When trying to install Linux, I am getting this:

```
NAND Low-level formating...
NAND Low-level formatted...

Superboot-210
Ver: 1.2(20120202)
CPU: S5PV210 1GHz
RAM: 512MB
NAND: 1GB(SLC) ID:ECD35195
Touch Device: no 1-wire
LCD Type: A70(Manu)

Installing OS 'LINUX'
Installing bootloader...
file: /images/Superboot210.bin: 528 KB(540672 Byte)
Installing bootloader succeed
Installing kernel...
file: /images/Linux/zImage: 4 MB(4810580 Byte)
Installing kernel succeed
Installing yaffs2-image...
Installing yaffs2-image failed
```

When trying the Android image:

```
NAND Low-level formating...
NAND Low-level formatted...

Superboot-210
Ver: 1.2(20120202)
CPU: S5PV210 1GHz
RAM: 512MB
NAND: 1GB(SLC) ID:ECD35195
Touch Device: no 1-wire
LCD Type: A70(Manu)

Installing OS 'ANDROID'
Installing bootloader...
file: /images/Superboot210.bin: 528 KB(540672 Byte)
Installing bootloader succeed
Installing kernel...
file: /images/Android/zImage: 4 MB(4590948 Byte)
Installing kernel succeed
Installing yaffs2-image...
Installing yaffs2-image failed
```

[This FRIENDLYARM FORUM post](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/5161) suggests that the image is a MLC2 NAND image whereas the NAND is SLC. I have tried rebuilding the image using the `rootfs` TAR but I am getting the same issue.

Any pointers are most welcome.

### [Also posted question on FriendlyARM forum](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/6265#lastpost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get `rootfs_qtopia_qt4-20121108.tar.gz` from the friendlyARM DVD
- Compiled [yaffs2utils](https://code.google.com/p/yaffs2utils/) on my dev environment.

#### Rebuilt the image

```
sudo tar xvf rootfs_qtopia_qt4-20121108.tar.gz
sudo mkyaffs2 rootfs_qtopia_qt4 rootfs_qtopia_qt4.img
```

and copied to my microSD card and adjusted my `FriendlyARM.ini` to take this file instead of the MLC2 NAND flash version.